# Changing android:configChanges dynamically

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am creating a magazine app which uses a `ViewPager` and scrolls over different `WebView`s.
Most of the pages are portrait but some of them can be seen as landscape.

To handle this, I am using two methods in the `Activity` holding the `ViewPager`:

```
public void allowOrientationChanges() {
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);
}

public void enforcePortrait() {
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
}
```

With this we make sure that all the pages that just need to be portrait stay portrait (calling `getActivity().enforcePortrait()`) and the ones that have portrait/landscape views goes through the whole restart process (calling `getActivity().allowOrientationChanges()`).

We reached a point where we want to add video to some of the magazine's pages. Unfortunately the HTML5 video tag isn't working fine so we added a `VideoView` to our layout.
The feature to add now is:

- in portrait: Showing the video in a certain place. (**Done!**)
- in landscape: Making the video full screen (like the youtube app).

I have been trying to do this and the only way I found is changing the size of the `VideoView` in the `onConfigurationChanged()` method in the `Activity` and notifying the `fragment` that the configuration changed. The problem with this is adding `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"` to the `Activity` will "disallow" the views to be recreated.

The two possible solutions I thought of:

1. Changing the `android:configChanges` from the code and depending on the page but I couldn't find if that call exists.
2. Forcing a recreate on the `onConfigurationChanged()` method. I don't know how to force a recreation of the `fragment`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just fixed it. Thanks for your answers.

My solution was to make the `Activity` have the `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"` flag.

After doing that I override the `onConfigurationChanged()` method inside the `Fragment` where I resize the `WebView` or the `VideoView` depending on what I need.

EDIT:

I just did a [blog post](http://android-argentina.blogspot.com/2011/09/playing-with-new-viewpager-class.html) about this.

Comment: This implementation is simple and works well in the [_Coinverse_ app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=app.coinverse)! I overrode `onConfigurationChanged` in a **DialogFragment** in order to have a **ExoPlayer** and embedded **YouTube** player view seamlessly play content without interruption from an orientation change. In `onConfigurationChanged` I updated the **DialogFragment** dimensions to keep the content proportional to the screen orientation.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe there is a way around it by defining the activity twice in the manifest with similar names and setting the second incarnation to enabled=false. Then switch the 2 activities around dynamically by calling [PackageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(....)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#setComponentEnabledSetting%28android.content.ComponentName,%20int,%20int%29) it is just an idea though, not sure it if will work.

Comment: I have just read a little about the `setComponentEnabledSetting()` method. The problem with it is that it needs a `ComponentName` which is created with the package name and the class name, so the activities' names can't be equal. If this would be the solution it would be the same as defining two different `activities` and launching them when the page scrolls which doesn't sound fine :(

Answer (score 2):

> I am creating a magazine app which uses a ViewPager and scrolls over different WebViews.

Is this reliable?

> Most of the pages are portrait but some of them can be seen as landscape.

Please allow all pages to be viewed in landscape. If your users want to view your app in landscape -- for example, they do not feel like turning their television on its side just to use your app -- please let them.

> Any ideas?

In `onResume()` of the activity, have it notify the magazine page fragment to fix up its `VideoView` size/position based on the then-current `Configuration` (`getResources().getConfiguration()`).

Comment: a) What you mean by reliable? b) Most of the pages are full screen images and unfortunately I don't have the resources to show them in landscape mode. c) I thought of adding that logic in the `onResume()` method but this will mean that the video is re-created. Not only a waste of resources but also I need to add all the logic to `seekTo()`.

Comment: @Macarse: 'What you mean by reliable?" -- I would expect the `ViewPager` and `WebView` to fight over touch events. "this will mean that the video is re-created" -- true. However, I have the funny feeling that you won't be able to get what you want. I don't know if either of your two specific ideas (at the bottom of your question) are possible.